Secure Public APIs through APIM for service to service use?
I'm going over methods to expose a subset of APIs through Azure API manager and how to keep things secure. The purpose would be for partners to build their own apps that connect to these APIs.
Right now, I'm thinking of utilizing both oAUTH2 (Client credential flow) and subscription keys. We create client ID/secrets in our tenant and we create a subscription key in APIM tied to products based on the APIs they need. They then obtain a token with client ID/secret and pass along the subscription key in order to access the backend APIs. Token gets validated through a JWT check.
I've already tested and this works well- but my question is, is the oauth portion necessary? I'm not sure I'm comfortable with only the subscription key securing the call but I don't want to over complicate setup either.
On top of this, would this also mean we have to create a new app reg/secret for each partner needing access and update the valid audiences in the JWT check or is there a better way to handle that? Trying to prevent unnecessary clutter in the tenant and with setup.

You can use the existing app while creating the OAuth in APIM. Also please specify your requirement clearly

I like to create app registrations that represent the APIs in APIM.  I define app roles that clients and users can be given that will be added to their JWT claims, and I require an audience claim that matches the API's app registration and a role claim that gives them access to that API.  I assume you're using either the validate-azure-ad-token policy or the validate-jwt policy for your oAuth, and both of those policies allow you to require specific audience and role claims.  At that point, you don't need to use subscription keys.
Since this is all through Entra Id, the validate-azure-ad-token policy is the easiest to use:
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="{{MyTenantId}}">
            <audiences>
                <audience>{{ThisApiAppRegistrationId}}</audience>
                <audience>api://{{ThisApiAppRegistrationId}}</audience>
                <!-- I like to put both of these audiences in here since they can both be valid depending on how the client requests their token. -->
            </audiences>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="roles" match="any">
                    <value>ThisApi.Call</value><!-- Any roles you put here must be defined in the API's app registration and granted to the caller. -->
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-azure-ad-token>
        <!-- Put the validation before the base in case you want to add a global policy to remove incoming authentication. -->
        <base />
    </inbound>
    ...
</policies>

If you're uncomfortable with creating an app registration for each client, and your clients are also in Entra Id, you can grant the app roles to users or app registrations that they create.
